# force ssl admin area to one site in multi site network with multiple networks wordpress

Tags: wordpress

real new to php...

I have a multi site worpress install running two networks..

The first network has a ssl cert but the second one does not.

I an currently using the define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);  in the wp config file to force the login and admin area to be secure.

Problem is the second network does not have the ssl so getting browser warnings when trying to access the login screen of the second netowrk.

My first site with the ssl is fanpage4me.com  and the second one withouth the ssl but using the same wp config file because of the multi site is scottheliker.com

Would anybody be kind enough to paste the exact code here I would need to put in my wp config file to only force the  define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);  to the first domain which is fanpage4me.com

Thanks Scott...

I also need to force ssl to all the sub sites of the first network when they get created automatically if that is possible.. right now the home and site url get prefixed with http instead of https so have to manually go in and changed evertime someone creates a blog..

Answer (score 1):

In your wp-config.php file just wrap your define in an if statement.

```
if ( $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] == "fanpage4me.com" ) {
  define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);
}
```

I've used this technique for several options and multi-domain wordpress sites.

Tony

Comment: Mad Props Tony... I was using this I found over the weekend which caused my not to be able to login...  $host = parse_url($domain, PHP_URL_HOST);
if($host == 'fanpage4me.com') {
    define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);
}
Can this be done to force https on only all my subsites of fanpage4me.com also?

Comment: Problem I am having is that when people created subsites on my main netowrk domain which has the ssl  the home url and site url get defaulted to http instead of https and I dont want to have to go in and change every one of the manually...  I applied this to my htaccess file but cause my second domain that does not have a cert to force https also  
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

Comment: I would love to find a way to do this using the wp config file also... forcing all the newly created subsites to use the https prefix for the fanpage4me.com domain while leaving the scottheliker.com domain alone?? thanks for your help... really appreciate it  Scott